# Filling a node with white space to put labels in the foreground

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have grid lines drawn on the Cartesian plane.  I mark distances `2`, `4`, `6`, and `8` along the x-axis and `2` along the y-axis.  To avoid the grid lines being drawn over these labels, I use `fill=white` and `inner sep=0.15` in the options for the node commands.  It seems to me that the display does not have the labels surrounded with `0.15cm` of white space.  How do I get the requested white space without moving the labels?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Horizontal grid lines are drawn.
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (-0.75,-0.5) -- (4.25,-0.5);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (-0.75,0) -- (4.25,0);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (-0.75,0.5) -- (4.25,0.5);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (-0.75,1) -- (4.25,1);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (-0.75,1.5) -- (4.25,1.5);

%Vertical grid lines are drawn.
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (-0.5,-0.75) -- (-0.5,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (0,-0.75) -- (0,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (0.5,-0.75) -- (0.5,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (1,-0.75) -- (1,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (1.5,-0.75) -- (1.5,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (2,-0.75) -- (2,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (2.5,-0.75) -- (2.5,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (3,-0.75) -- (3,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (3.5,-0.75) -- (3.5,1.75);
\draw[dashed,gray!50] (4,-0.75) -- (4,1.75);


%Some distances from the origin along the axes are labeled.
\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15, font=\tiny] at ($(1,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2};
\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15, font=\tiny] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.15)$){4};
\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15, font=\tiny] at ($(3,0) +(0,-0.15)$){6};
\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.15, font=\tiny] at ($(4,0) +(0,-0.15)$){8};

\node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.15, font=\tiny] at ($(0,1) +(-0.15,0)$){2};


%The axes are drawn.
\draw[latex-latex] (-1,0) -- (4.5,0);
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,2);
\node [anchor=north west] at (4.5,0) {$x$};
\node [anchor=south west] at (0,2) {$y$};


%A path is drawn.
\draw (0,-0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,0) -- (2,1) -- (3,1) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (4,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want the nodes to move, you could, if you really wanted to, fill *behind* them after they are drawn. You would need a layer in between the plot and the nodes. At least, that would be easiest, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer offers two solutions, one with `pgfplots` and one with `tikz`.

## `pgfplots`

This would be much easier to do with `pgfplots`, you don't need to draw everything manually.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1, xmax=9,
    ymin=-1, ymax=2,
    axis equal,
    minor y tick num=1,
    minor x tick num=1,
    yticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white},
    xticklabel style={font=\scriptsize, fill=white},
    axis lines=center, no markers,
    grid=both, grid style={dashed,gray,very thin},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
]

\plot[black,thick] coordinates {(0,-1) (2,1) (3,0) (4,2) (6,2) (7,1) (8,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

## `tikz`

If you want to keep using TikZ, here's an alternative version. Your problem is that you said `inner sep=0.15` but didn't specify the type of measurement. Try writing `inner sep=0.15cm` and you'll see the difference.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}%{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\myshift{.10}
\newcommand\xmax{5}
\newcommand\ymax{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% axes + grid
\draw[step=5mm,gray,dashed, line width=.2pt] ({\xmax-5.75},{\ymax-3.75}) grid ({\xmax-.25},{\ymax-.25});
\draw[latex-latex] (-1,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[font=\tiny, right] {$x$};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,{\ymax-4.25}) -- (0,\ymax)   node[font=\tiny, above] {$y$};

% x tick labels
\foreach \label [count=\xx] in {2,4,6,8}{%
    \node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=\myshift cm, font=\tiny] at (\xx,0) {\label};
}

% y tick labels
\foreach \label [evaluate=\label as \yy using int(\label/2)] in {-2,2,4}{%
    \node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=\myshift cm, font=\tiny] at (0,\yy) {\label};
}

%A path is drawn.
\draw (0,-0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,0) -- (2,1) -- (3,1) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (4,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Alenanno.  It has been a long time.  I want to keep the code in `TikZ`.

Comment: @Adelyn Hello! :) See edit.

Comment: Your code is more efficient.  I have not referred to the manual to use the `\foreach` command.  I should refer to this post later for that.

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between `inner sep=0.15` and `inner sep=0.15cm`.  Isn't the default measurement in centimeters?  Apparently, it isn't the default for measurements in the options of a `node` command.  What does `inner sep=0.15` do?

Comment: I like the spacing provided by the option `anchor=north` and the location `($(1,0) +(0,-0.15)$)` for the labels `2`, `4`, `6`, and `8` below the `x`-axis.  The only modification that I want is to have some white space about them - without pushing the labels downward.

Comment: @Adelyn I am not sure what `. 15` does, but I think it's in points in that case. My yshift is there so you don't have to do the Calc,  why would you prefer that?

Comment: You may be right about what `0.15` does.  From the code in the post, there is almost no space between the labels and the grid lines.  I want to use the `calc` package to position the labels to be consistent with other code in a file.

Comment: Using the positioning that I have in my code, how do I get `0.15cm` of white space about the labels - without pushing the labels along the `x`-axis downward and without pushing the label along the `y`-axis leftward?

Comment: @Adelyn just set a bigger inner sep.

Comment: Using any positive value for `inner sep` pushes the labels along the `x`-axis downward.

Comment: @Adelyn So you want the labels to stay where they are like when `inner sep` is `0`?

Comment: @Adelyn I edited the Tikz version. Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: I see that you added something equivalent to `text height=0.15cm` as an option to the node command.  I have not seen such an option in the manual.  What does it instruct `TikZ` to do?  It is not quite what I want, which is `2`, `4`, `6`, and `8` anchored at `north` and these anchors `0.15cm` below the `x`axis; surrounding each node should be white space `0.05cm` wide. I think this code can be modified to get me what I want.

Comment: @Adelyn as soon as I get back on my computer, I'll show you some variants, so you tell me which one you want.

Comment: The display that you got with `pgfplots` is what I want using options of the `node` command in `TikZ`.

Comment: @Adelyn See edit.

Comment: I replaced your commands `\newcommand\myshift{.10}`,
`\newcommand\xmax{5}`, and `\newcommand\ymax{2.5}` in the preamble and substituted the appropriate values in your code.  `TikZ` cannot compile the edited code.  I posted this edited code so that you can just copy-and-paste it and try to compile it yourself.  I get the error "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."  What is the error?  I have not used the `\foreach` command or the option `\count=xx` for the `\label command.  See the code below.  I

Comment: I am willing to mark your post as the accepted answer.  I need to compile the adaptation of your code that I provided at the bottom of this post.  (I removed the grid lines.)

Comment: @Adelyn ok,  I'll check it out asap.

Answer (score 7):

I can imagine why you might want to stick with TikZ syntax for self-confidence, familiarity and so on, but I would still recommend `pgfplots` for this or at least TikZ' own `graphdrawing` library.

Anyways, for the inner sep outer sep stuff, maybe a visualization might help.

The node contents are put in a placeholder (an `\hbox` or `minipage` environment and then TikZ measures this placeholder height and width to draw the node shape. `inner sep` is added to this measurement.

`outer sep` is kind of the same idea but works differently. When you want to place something next to it or draw a line to/from this node or simply place the node itself by mentioning the border anchors, it computes the point on the border and then retracts `outer sep` many points away from the node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,outer sep=1cm,inner sep=1cm] (a){\fbox{Contents}} ;

\draw[|-|,thick,red] (a.south) node[below,black]{Here is south anchor} 
    --++(0,1cm) node[midway,right]{1cm (outer sep)};
\draw[|-|,thick,red] (a.south) ++(0,1cm) 
    --++(0,1cm)node[midway,right]{1cm (inner sep)};
\node[text width=1.5cm,align=right,inner sep=0,outer sep=0,draw,left] 
    (b) at(a.west) {a relative placed node};
\draw[|-|,blue,thick] (b.east) -- ++(1cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As you can see, the padding is now a bit more visible. Now when you anchor your labels the outer sep is pushing them below as you have seen already. But anchoring doesn't need to be absolute you can still nudge things around via:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[outer sep=0cm,inner sep=0cm] (O){O} ;
\node[outer sep=1cm,inner sep=1cm,draw,anchor=north,yshift=1cm] at (O) {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

We see that even if the anchor is set to north we can still shift things around and anchor is still respected.

Comment: Using this information, how would you put the requested white space about each node as suggested in the post?  I am not that familiar with `TikZ`.  I think that I can get the desired display with the following two commands for each node:  `\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\tiny] at ($(1,0) +(0,-0.15)$){2};` and `\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.075cm, font=\tiny] at ($(1,0) +(0,-0.15)$){\phantom{2}};`.  It may not be efficient, but it does "frame" the node with `0.075cm` of white space.  Right?

Comment: @percusse  Your code showing the boxes surrounding a node with `inner sep` and `outer sep` is useful.  I now have code that gives me the desired placement of the nodes and white space surrounding them:  `\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.1cm, font=\tiny] at ($(1,0) +(0,-0.05)$){2};`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative possible solution with TikZ:

[image]

It is generated by the following (to my opinion very concise) code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
% for show only a picture
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    x=5mm,  y=5mm,
AL/.style = {% Axis Labels 
   fill=white, inner sep=0.5mm, font=\tiny} 
                        ]
% grid
\draw[gray,dashed,very thin] (-1,-3) grid[step=1] (9,5); 
% x tick labels
\foreach \x in {2,4,6,8}
    \node[AL,below=1mm] at (\x,0) {\x}; 
% y tick labels
\foreach \y in {-2,2,4}
\node[AL,left=1mm] at (0,\y) {\y};
% x and y axes
\draw[latex-latex] (-1,0) -- (9,0) node[AL,below left=1mm and 0mm] {$x$};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,5) node[AL,below left=0mm and 1mm] {$y$};
% curve
\draw[red, very thick]
    (0,-1) -- (2,1) -- (3,0) -- 
    (4, 2) -- (6,2) -- (7,1) -- (8,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In above code I use:

- grid for drawing grid of graph. With selection `step=5mm` are defined distances between grid lines. It is equal to size of `x` and `y` units for distances in those directions.
- style for x and y tick label are defined in `tikzpicture` options. For `inner sep`, i.e. distance between *text in node* and *node's border*, I select 0,5 mm. In it positioning I select that nodes are 1 mm from axis, so distance between them and numbers is sum of both distances (1.5 mm).

Comment: I just made a comment to Percusse that is similar to what you did, I think.  Your anchors for the labels along the `x`-axis are not `north`, though.  How would you adjust your code for that?  (Where is there a description for `AL/.style`?)

Comment: @user143462, definition of AL style is mine (you can defined similarly common styles and picture features) and it is in option of `tikzpicture`. With it I achieve two things: (i) all tick and axis label have the same style (ii) the code is shorter. About anchors: (i) you can say `anchor=north` and node will placed below given coordinate or (ii) say `below` and node will be positioned also below given coordinate.  In second case you can say haw much below you like to have, for example `below= 1mm ` (as used in my MWE). With package positioning you can use even more sophisticated positioning.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% axes + grid
\draw[step=5mm,gray,dashed, line width=0.2pt] (-0.75,-1.25) grid (4.25,2.25);
\draw[latex-latex] (-1,0) -- (5,0) node[font=\tiny, right] {$x$};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-1.75) -- (0,2.5)   node[font=\tiny, above] {$y$};

% x tick labels
\foreach \label [count=\xx] in {2,4,6,8}
{\node[fill=white, anchor=north, inner sep=0.1cm, font=\tiny] at (\xx,0) {\label};}

% y tick labels
\foreach \label [evaluate=\label as \yy using int(\label/2)] in {-2,2,4}
{\node[fill=white, anchor=east, inner sep=0.1cm, font=\tiny] at (0,\yy) {\label};}

%A path is drawn.
\draw (0,-0.5) -- (1,0.5) -- (1.5,0) -- (2,1) -- (3,1) -- (3.5,0.5) -- (4,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code is a modification of code from Alenanno.  `TikZ` cannot compile it.   "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."

Comment: It works without any errors for me. What does the full error say? I mean what line is it referring to?

Comment: @Alenanno  It does not tell me any line.  You copy-and-pasted this code and it compiled for you?!

Comment: yes,  no errors or warnings. Not sure why you're having a problem... Your Tex Live distribution is up to date?

Comment: @Alenanno The error message included "[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 06.09.02).]"   I was using `WinEdt 8.1`.  Apparently, something has to be updated.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Alenanno   I just compiled the code on the current editor - `WinEdt 9.1` - and it rendered a display.  I can now talk about the display.  The white space surrounding the tick marks interferes with the axes.  If I replace ` at (\xx,0)` with ` at (\xx,-0.05)` for the tick marks along the `x`-axis, the display is what I want.